# Why is some .htaccess <FilesMatch> tutorial usually wrapped within <IfModule mod_headers.c>?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cache-control, apache-config

I'd want to configure the cache-control of a file like this.

```
<FilesMatch "service-worker.js$">
Header set Cache-Control "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>
```

This works on my server.

However, I've seen several tutorials that do this.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>

<FilesMatch "service-worker.js$">
Header set Cache-Control "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>

</IfModule>
```

They also have a wrapper named `IfModule mod headers.c>`.

What's the difference between these two?

What happens if I don't enclose my code within the `IfModule`?

Comment: Then your directive won’t work if that Apache module isn’t installed and enabled.

Comment: "They also have a wrapper named `IfModule mod headers.c>`" - That doesn't make sense as written (and will likely cause the enclosed directives to be bypassed entirely).

Comment: "I've seen several tutorials that do this." - and they probably shouldn't. Unfortunately, these Apache config directives are too often blindly copy/pasted and bad practice propagates.